# CF Deployment causing DB to Crash in SAP CAP based project

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

We are trying to deploy some enhancements to a custom application which is based on SAP Cloud Application programming model, SAP HANA on cloud and deployed on CF. As a part of these enhancements, we are trying to use SDI and create virtual tables in the database container via deployment. There are some virtual tables which this solution already relies upon but as a part of enhancements 9 new virtual were introduced in the solution. When trying to deploy the solution with these new virtual tables its failing to deploy only the database module, other modules such as UI, SRV and approuter are not getting effected. What could be the root cause?

Additionally, tried to minimize the changes and just tried to deploy the original app with just 1 virtual table and even that caused database to crash.

Some of the logs from the failed DB module:

Some of the common errors that we see in the logs are:
`Error: com.sap.hana.di.virtualtable: Database error 259: invalid table name:  Could not find table/view com.sap.hana.di.virtualtable#VIRTUAL_TABLES in schema BFFB38876DED474D8286C3F6B5F392B0#DI: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7) [8201003] Error: com.sap.hana.di.virtualtable: Could not create the virtual table in the database [8254003]  Error: Worker 1 has encountered an error; all remaining jobs will be canceled [8214600] Error: Processing work list... failed [8212102] Error: Making... failed [8211605] Error: Starting make in the container "BFFB38876DED474D8286C3F6B5F392B0" with 1 files to deploy, 0 files to undeploy... failed [8214168]`

Comment: This seems to be an error in the HDI deployment likely not caused by CAP. You should probably look into the documentation of the features you use to create those tables.

Comment: @Niklas thanks for your comments, yes its during deployment i encounter this error. It seems to be looking for a table in DI schema which resembles our HDI container(BFFB38876DED474D8286C3F6B5F392B0) albeit ending with #DI, not sure why that table is not present. When i try to deploy with new ID and create new instance of DB it deploys without any problem and I see that table name does get generated in the DI schema of the new HDI container.

Comment: Ultimately this issue was resolved, it was due the SAP HANA Cloud Database version was not upgraded for a while, upon upgrading it to a latest release, this was resolved.